# Oreo WebView background color is wrong when calling loadData after loadUrl

Tags: android, android-webview

When setting the background color to be transparent and then using loadUrl, everything works as intended. As soon as loadData is called the background color changes to white. 
When using only loadData without previously using loadUrl the background color is also correct.

This behavior was only observed in Android Oreo.

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Integer.parseInt("55FF4081", 16));
    setContentView(ll);

    final WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    ll.addView(wv, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    wv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    wv.loadUrl("https://slack.com");

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            wv.loadData("test", "text/html", "utf-8");
        }
    }, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in chromium and is fixed with version 66.